# Как получить имя переменной в виде строки?

Tags: javascript

Не значение переменной, а именно её имя.

Comment: используй объект и его ключ->значение `var obj = { myFirstName: 'John' };
obj.foo = 'Another name';
for(key in obj)
    alert(key + ': ' + obj[key]);`

Answer (score 6):

Хм, да никак.
Можно, однако, сделать такой финт:

```js
(function() {
  var getVarName = function tmp(){
    let n = /getVarName\(([^)]+?)\)/.exec(tmp.caller !== null ? tmp.caller.toString() : '');
    
    return n !== null ? n[1] : false;
  }
  
  let myVarName123456 = 1;
  console.info(getVarName(myVarName123456)); // myVarName123456
}());
```

Но это грязный хак, неудобный и больше только "сделать на спор", чем рабочий; в реальном коде даже не знаю кто мог бы это использовать.

---

Возможно стоит пересмотреть архитектуру Вашего проекта, где используется идентификатор переменной как зависимая величина.
Переменные как раз и придумали чтобы не зависеть от названий.

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы получить имя вы должны переменную обернуть объектом, вот так:

```
<script>
    var myVariable = {};
    myVariable["myVariable"] = 5; // заварачиваем переменную в массив

    myVariable["myVariable"] = 7; // вот так работаем с переменной

    alert(myVariable["myVariable"]); // вот так получаем ее значение

    function getName(arrayVariable){ // функция для извлечения имени
        for (key in arrayVariable)
            return key;
    }

    alert(getName(myVariable)); // извлекаем имя
</script>
```

Comment: ой какой плохой пример :-) зачем там массив, если используется он как объект? :)

Comment: @Grundy в данном контексте, если обернуть переменную в объект то ничего не изменится, как мне кажется.

Comment: о том и речь, а раз используется только как объект - то надо и создавать объект, а не массив

Comment: @Grundy ну если вы считаете это принципиальным то исправлю код, а то уже кто то поддался вашей тенденции и минус поставил )

Comment: Ага :-) я и поставил :) ну и лучше литерал `{}` в данном случае испльзовать

Comment: заменил на литералы

Answer (score 3):

Переменная не хранит подобную информации о себе, а значит получить ее строковое представление имени у Вас не получится.

Максимум, что вы можете сделать, это зная контекст переменной попытаться получить ее имя через родителя. Да и то, если только эта переменная является ссылочным объектом, а не переменной значения.

```
function context(){
    this.a = { "test" : "test" };

    for(key in this){
        if(this[key] == a) console.log(key);
    }
}
context();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var variable = "something";
var variableName = Object.keys({ variable })[0];

console.log(variableName)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать, но переменная должна быть объектом, и ему необходимо дать уникальное свойство или метод по которому его можно будет отличить в списке прочих переменных. Получить и перебрать список переменных, среди которых окажется искомая, внутри документа можно вот так

```
for (var variable in window) {
    //Анализ variable - она или не она
}
```

Внутри надо юзать `eval` и `typeof` чтобы получить доступ к объекту по его имени и определить наличие уникального свойства/метода. Немного нагружает браузер клиента, зато работает. Протестировано в фоксе.

Вот пример

```
var Class = function() {
}
Class.prototype.isOurVariable = function() {return true};

var object123 = new Class(); //Ищем имя этой переменной
for (var variable in window) {
    if (!/[a-z]+/.test(variable)) {
        //отсекаем свойства типа "0", есть такие
        continue;
    }
    eval("var ok = (" + variable  + " != null && typeof (" + variable + ".isOurVariable) != 'undefined');");
    if (ok) {console.log(variable); break} 
}
```

Comment: а если переменной нет в window?

Comment: а строка eval, спокойно заменяется на: `var ok = (window[variable] != null && typeof (window[variable].isOurVariable) != 'undefined');`

Comment: У меня в window всё есть.

Comment: а у меня нет. Любая локальная переменная в функции - не добавляется в window. Поэтому стоит либо добавить эти ограничения в ответ, либо удалить его

Comment: Даже просто заменив `var object123` на `let object123` - код ломается и не работает

Comment: Уважаемый, знаете в чем разница между моим ответом и вашими умностями? Сегодня утром у меня была задача получить имя переменной и я это решил этим рецептом и поделился им. Ваш комментарий о window[property] без этого рецепта бесполезен а мой рецепт и без него дает тот же результат. И ни один Ваш комментарий не поможет решить такую же задачу, а мой рецепт - да. Всего доброго, тема закрыта.

Comment: Суть в том, что если объекта не будет в window, ваш код так же бесполезен.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, это то что вы ищете:

```
const num = '15';
const [numVar] = Object.keys({num});
console.log(numVar, num) // num 15
```

теперь в numVar содержится имя переменной/константы "num"

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: И чем ваш ответ от [соседнего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1513286/532877) отличается?

Comment: @Зонтик тем что это деструктуризация массива и удобнее таким образом брать имена нескольких переменных сразу, если они есть. Это решение кажется мне более элегантным и универсальным.
    const num = '15';
    const num2 = '16';
    const [numVar, num2Var] = Object.keys({num, num2});